# adding post to blogger nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, blogger

I have been trying to add post to blogger using api in nodejs. I get the success message but no title or content being added to the post. Just blank posts are being created. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise');
const google = require ('googleapis');
const Youtube = require("youtube-api");
const blogger = google.google.blogger('v3')
    , fs = require("fs")
    , readJson = require("r-json")
    , Lien = require("lien")
    , Logger = require("bug-killer")
    , opn = require("opn")
    , prettyBytes = require("pretty-bytes")
    ;

// I downloaded the file from OAuth2 -> Download JSON
const CREDENTIALS = readJson('./bcreds.json');

// Init lien server
let server = new Lien({
    host: "localhost"
  , port: 6111
});


let oauth = Youtube.authenticate({
    type: "oauth"
  , client_id: CREDENTIALS.web.client_id
  , client_secret: CREDENTIALS.web.client_secret
  , redirect_url: CREDENTIALS.web.redirect_uris[0]
});

opn(oauth.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline"
  , scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger"]
}));

// Handle oauth2 callback
server.addPage("/oauth2callback", lien => {
    Logger.log("Trying to get the token using the following code: " + lien.query.code);
    oauth.getToken(lien.query.code, (err, tokens) => {

        if (err) {
            lien.lien(err, 400);
            return Logger.log(err);
        }

        Logger.log("Got the tokens.");

        oauth.setCredentials(tokens);

        lien.end("The post is being uploaded. Check out the logs in the terminal.");

// write below

        blogger.posts.insert({
                auth: oauth,
                blogId: "blog id here",
                resource: {
                  content: "postContent",
                  title: "postTitle",
                },  
            }, function(err, success){
                console.log(success);
            });

        // end
    });
});
```

Please help in getting understand that where is the problem. The code runs correctly and it do add post but the post is just blank.

Comment: Do you have an error message? The code seems to work. and creates the content. At least for me.

Comment: It is now working. I have fixed the problem

Comment: Do you know what the Problem was? If so could you share your findings? Or did, it just start working?